# Why there is a non-linear trend on the melting points for period 2 elements, especially Na to Si?

Tags: materials, melting-point

Using the knowledge of periodicity from high school cannot explain this, what it tells me is just metallic bonding.

The model of delocalised electron from a metallic lattice can explain the increase of melting point from Na to Si, but it fails to explain why the relationship is non-linear?

Comment: Why should it be linear in the first place?

Comment: What I mean is the m.p. of Al and Mg is almost same, and Si is almost doubled the amount, why? The high school textbook says this "period 2 element has linear increase on m.p. from Na to Si because of the amount of delocalised electrons", but I don't think this works as Al has more delocalised electron according to this but same m.p.

Comment: Not surprisingly, high school textbooks tend to simplify things, and offer simple explanations even for things that they should not try to explain. Looking for simple explanations for non-existent trends may only lead to madness... (hopefully just being mad at the textbook, mind you).

Comment: The number of delocalized electrons hardly matters at all. See, in molten metal these electrons are still delocalized and feel pretty much the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your textbook says that the melting point increases *linearly*, that is incorrect, as you point out. Generally high school textbooks can only make broad, qualitative statements about characteristics like melting points since the physics involved can depend to a larg degree on very complicated (quantum mechanical) interactions between the atoms (and their electrons) in a solid.

See for instance http://www.ptable.com/, and try playing with the slider on the top right to see melting points for different elements. There is a general trend of heavier metals in the same period having higher melting points, but there are some exceptions, such as manganese (Mn) around 1570 K.

As for why specifically Si's melting point is so much higher than Al's, the only truly correct answer is something along the lines of "that's just because of the differences in the way Si and Al atoms interact with each other". Because that's not a very satisfying explanation, I can try to paint a more intuitive picture: (UPDATE: it has been pointed out in the comments that even this simplified picture is wrong, see the linked wikipedia article for more details.) Aluminium has three valence electrons, which means that it would need to form five covalent bonds with its neighbours in order to reach the favourable octet of electrons. Unfortunately there is no regular crystal structure where every atom has exactly five nearest neighbours, so what ends up happening is that one electron from each atom delocalises, and the resulting postively charged ions are weakly (i.e. noncovalently) bound to each other, resulting in a low melting point (in other words, the atoms can be shaken apart easily).

Silicon on the other hand, has four valence electrons, only one more than Al, but this means that it only needs to bind to four neighbours to get an octet, and it turns out that there is a regular arrangement of atoms such that each atom has exactly four nearest neighbours (called the diamond structure). So, in solid Silicon, each atom is covalently (and thus strongly) bound to four neighbours, (and no electrons delocalised) which means that the atoms are hard to shake apart, which leads to a much higher melting point.

Now, this might be a more pleasing explanation (at least I hope so), but note that it is only meant for illustrative purposes: the same logic, dealing with 3 vs. 4 valence atoms can also be applied to for example Thallium and Lead, but these two metals have virtually the same melting point. Why is that? Well, there are other effects at play for these heavier atoms. In other words, it really does come down to how groups of the same atom interact with each other, and much of that can only be understood through the framework of quantum mechanics, and a rigorous treatment of solid state physics is probably too much to expect from a high school textbook :-)

Comment: Your picture for Al is wrong.

Comment: Your response is unilluminating.

Comment: Al wouldn't get octet with 5 neighbors. Boron has such situation but with elecrtodeficience. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropes_of_boron

Comment: Fair enough, I've edited the answer to add a disclaimer.